# Linq Left Join selecting a collection as a property

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, left-join

I'm new to Linq and I'm trying to join two table's - left join to be precise, I'm expecting top 10 results where the property of a result is a collection.

consider the sample model

```
Class A { int Id, List<B> Collection }
Class B { int Id, int x, int y }
```

I'm trying to perform left join such that the response I expect needs to be in the following format:

```
int A
Collection (part of B) =>{int x}
```

I tried with the following query

```
From A in _context.A 
Join B in (from B in _context.B select new {Id, x }) on B.Id equals A.Id Into subB
From minimalB in subB.defaultIfEmpty()
Select {A.Id, minimalB.x}
```

How do i achieve the result such that the x property maps in as a collection to the result.

I Apologize for absurd explanation of the question in prior!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need `from minimalB in subB.defaultIfEmpty` part, because it will create something similar to a cartesian product from your sets of data which represented as range variables (`a` and `minimalB` ). So to have a collection of `X`-s, you can try the following:

```
var query = from a in context.A
            join b in context.B on a.Id equals b.Id into groupedB
            where groupedB.Any()
            select new { a.Id, Xs = groupedB.Select(b => b.X) };
```

By the way, if you already have the `B` collection in your `A` class, you can make the query without explicit joins (under the hood the query provider still will make join)

```
var query = _context.A.Select(a => new 
                    { 
                        a.Id,
                        Bs = a.Collection.Select(b => new { b.X, b.Y }) 
                    });
```

Comment: I will bet $50 US that practically no one knows what a Cartesian Product is in this context. Let alone why it's a bad thing.

Comment: Is the include mandatory? I mean it works even without the include right?

Comment: @CaptainKenpachi Can you please explain in simple terms?

Comment: No, it's not always mandatory, I think you can have lazy loading configured, so that it will load the collection if you need it

Comment: Given two sets `A` and `B`, Cartesian Product of them is a set of all pairs `(a, b)`, where `a` is an element of `A` and `b` is an element of `B`. Informally, your sets are represented using two range variables `a` and `minimalB`, so that the result will be the set (or sequence in terms of c# language) of all pairs between values from `A` and `B` like `{ (a1, b1), (a1, b2), (a2, b1), (a2, b2) }`

Comment: @E.Shcherbo Thing is i'm trying to get the data from like 15-18 tables(all related to each other) and each table contain million data may be or more, the api just times out due to the time it takes to query the data is there any way to optimize it?

Comment: It's hard to tell, I would suggest you to try to execute queries in pure `SQL` first using whatever server client you wish to figure out what you need to optimize - your db or your LINQ-queries. Then you can use SQL profiler or something to check what requests your app sends to the SQL server to check to see if you can optimize them somehow.

Comment: The `Include` isn't necessary here, nor is lazy loading; the projection (`new`) is enough to get all data. And I wouldn't mention the first query, because using `join` should never be considered when navigation properties are available. That said, I'm a bit surprised that this seems to be the answer. The word `minimalB` suggests that OP was looking for some selection within `B` objects. Well, I guess it indeed is an *absurd explanation*.

Comment: @GertArnold thank you, that's useful to know about `Include`. With reference to your doubts the OP is looking for a way to get a sequence of objects of the following shape: `{ int Id, IEnumerable<int> Xs }`,  so it looks exactly like `group join`

Comment: @GertArnold How do i do this?? "The word minimalB suggests that OP was looking for some selection within B objects" I was actually looking for it but since my approach seemed wrong i thought it was fine to go with the mentioned approach, I do know how to select individual members with the above method but is there any better efficient way?

Comment: @Comraid could you please clarify then what exactly you need? In the question you're saying that you need `{A, Collection of X}`, is it right? Or do you need **single** `X`, which is minimal?

Comment: @E.Shcherbo Okay let me try to explain it to ya in a simple way, So i want to join two tables eg table A, B where A has one to many relationship with B, I can just join and select the columns but its taking a lot of time, but i thought why not join just the limited column from the table B instead of whole table! i tried to do that but i cannot map the relationship properly! I do not get a collection as mapped to table A, hence I'm trying to group them then join, but I'm not able to figure it out! is it possible to help me out?

Comment: @GertArnold with the mentioned method It works as i wanted, but what I was trying to do was instead of joining A with the whole table I was trying to join with the subset of the table B and get similar result as the above query. is that even possible?

Comment: @Comraid you join your tables based on the `Id` column, what do you mean join with the **subset of the table**? I'm not sure if your performance will be improved if your `B` table have less columns (you can always check it by creating a view from the `B` table).

Comment: @E.Shcherbo Okay, even if i create the view it flattens the table in that case how do i group the related properties and get them as a collection in the result???

Comment: @Comraid related properties of the table `B`?

Comment: @E.Shcherbo Yes related properties of B, if I create views in order to get the data I will have to perform left join or left outer join right? but when i run the query i wont get the related data of table B as a collection in table A. Am i making sense or confusing you? again

Comment: @Comraid in that case you may want to consider the first query in my answer. Did you try it? It doesn't use navigation properties, but it relates each object of type `A` to objects which have properties of type `B`.

Comment: @Comraid by the way, I would first try it in *sql management studio* or something similar to make sure that it will improve performance of your query. And only after that I would try to express it in c# code.

Comment: @E.Shcherbo Yep i tried your first query but it says 'System.InvalidOperationException: Processing of the LINQ expression' and it can just select a single property not multiple properties

Comment: You can always select multiple props, e.g. `.Select(b => new { b.C, b.Y })`. Can you share the full error message, so that I will be able to help

Comment: @E.Shcherbo https://dotnetfiddle.net/DC8GYi I have copied the query as well as error message have a look and it doesnt allow me to select the second property after tagId

Comment: Well, you actually have navigation property called `Collection`, therefore you don't need use the query with `join` and I edited my answer to show you how you can select multiple properties using dot notation. But if you don't have a navigation property and have only `Ids` in your classes, then you want to consider the first query with explicit `join`.